# Necesito concatenar en una sola fila

Tags: sql-server

Necesito que solo se muestre una sola fila, para que donde dice código se junten
esto es el código que tengo

```
select
ev.ID,ev.Origen,
stuff(servicios.codigo,1,1,'')as codigo,
ev.Estatus,ev.Situacion,
ev.FechaEmision,
incidencia911.incidente,
incidenciaP.Tipo as CtPolicia, incidenciaP.Descripcion as CdPolicia,
incidenciaM.Tipo as CtModK, incidenciaM.Descripcion as CdModk,
ev.EventoDireccion,ev.Direccion,ev.DireccionEntreCalles,ev.DireccionNumero,ev.DireccionNumeroInt,ev.Colonia,ev.Municipio,
ev.MapaLatitudUTM,ev.MapaLongitudUTM,ev.Distrito,ev.cuadrante,ev.Telefono,ev.Nombre,ev.ApellidoPaterno,ev.ApellidoMaterno,ev.Sexo,ev.Edad
from Evento as ev
left join Evento_servicios as servicioID on servicioID.evento_id = ev.ID
left join ops_servicio as servicios on servicios.id = servicioID.servicio_id
left join EventoModuloK as emk on emk.IDEvento = ev.ID
left join EventoDetenido as evd on ev.ID = evd.IDEvento
left join Incidencia as incidencia911 on incidencia911.id = ev.incidencia_id
left join IncidenciaPECUU as incidenciaP on ev.incidenciapecuu_id = incidenciaP.ID
left join IncidenciaPECUU as incidenciaM on emk.incidenciapecuu_id = incidenciaM.ID
where ev.ID = 403285



Me sale así

ID               Código
----------      -------------
1               es
1               pm
1               v
```

Necesito que lo que esta en código me salga en una sola fila

Intente usar el stuff me me muestra lo mismo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Prueba a quitar el "ev.ID" del SELECT

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo de como utilizar el motedo stuff. 
SELECT STUFF('Pericardio', 5, 5, 'pl').
lo que hace es ir a la posición 5 (la "c" de "cardio"), eliminar 5 caracteres (o sea, "cardi"), y luego meter entre esa posición y lo que reste la cadena "pl".

Comment: Stuff no es una funcion que concatena... no se que tratas de hacer...

Comment: Esa no es la salida de la query. Puedes dejar un pequeño resumen de la salida de tú query. Todas las columnas que mencionas en la misma, eliminando, la parte del Stuff. Ejemplo: SELECT ev.ID, ev.Origen, ev.Estatus, ev.Situacion, ev.FechaEmision, incidencia911.incidente, incidenciaP.Tipo AS CtPolicia, incide.....FROM Evento AS ev ...

Comment: dependiendo de tu versión de SQL puedes utilizar la funcion CONCAT o convertir cada uno de tus campos a texto e ir concatenandolo con el signo +. Ejemplo: SELECT CONCAT(campo1, campo2, ...., campo n) o  SELECT 'texto1' + 'texto2'